# "Haben Sie sich vielleicht in den Kopf gesetzt, mich auch weiterhin nicht in Ruhe zu lassen?"

Tags: sentence-structure, grammatical-case, objects

This post is on the final sentence of this passage from chapter '[Der Fall Robinson](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/amerika-9768/21)' of *Amerika* (*Der Verschollene*) by Frankz Kafka.

> »Dann sage ich Ihnen und bitte Sie, Delamarche das gleiche auszurichten: Unser Abschied war, wenn das nicht schon an und für sich klar gewesen sein sollte, ein endgültiger. Sie beide haben mir mehr Leid getan als irgend jemand. **Haben Sie sich vielleicht in den Kopf gesetzt, mich auch weiterhin nicht in Ruhe zu lassen?**«

**QUESTION**

Should I think that *sich* is in the dative case (specifically one that tells us whose head, or Kopf, is being spoken of)?

Assuming that is right, how does grammar characterize *mich auch weiterhin nicht in Ruhe zu lassen*? Is it an accusative object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, *sich* is a dative object to the phrase *in den Kopf setzen*. *Who* is the receiver of the of the idea being put into someone's head? It's *sich* – *yourself*.

> Haben Sie sich vielleicht in den Kopf gesetzt, mich auch weiterhin nicht in Ruhe zu lassen?
>
> Haben Sie sich vielleicht in den Kopf gesetzt, dass Sie mich auch weiterhin nicht in Ruhe lassen?
>
> Haben Sie sich vielleicht das Stören in den Kopf gesetzt?

In the latter sentence, *das Stören* is an accusative object. In the original sentence, this object is replaced by an infinitive clause. The object clause with *dass* is an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Ja, es ist *sich (Dativ) etwas (Akkusativ) in den Kopf setzen*, der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kopf) sagt:

> sich  etwas in den Kopf setzen (fest entschlossen sein, etwas zu tun: er hat sich in den Kopf gesetzt, sie zu heiraten)